# Django rest api issue: hasattr(): attribute name must be string

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a simple blog application and I am trying to convert django rest api. But, I got this **error**

> **TypeError at /user/api/ hasattr(): attribute name must be string**
>
> **Exception Type: TypeError at /user/api/**
>
> **Exception Value: hasattr(): attribute name must be string**

this is my **models.py** file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blog_description=models.TextField()
    blog_pub=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    blog_update=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title


    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('blog:blog_post', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

this is my **serializers.py** file

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from blog.models import BlogPost


class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields=(
            'author',
            'blog_title',
            'blog_description',
        ),
        model=BlogPost
```

This is **views.py** file

```
from blog.models import BlogPost

from .serializers import BlogPostSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from . import serializers
from . import serializers


class BlogPostListAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset=BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class=BlogPostSerializer


class BlogPostListAPIDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.BlogPostSerializer
```

this is **urls.py** file

```
from django.urls import path,include

from .views import SignUpForm, UserProfiles
from .api.views import *


urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/',  SignUpForm.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('profile/', UserProfiles.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('api/', BlogPostListAPI.as_view(), name='asad'),
    path('api/<int:pk>', BlogPostListAPIDetail.as_view()),
]
```

this is **screenshot**
[image]

Comment: can't see where `hasttr` is used

Comment: All code shared. but I don't know how can I get this error. Also, I didn't use **hasttr**.

Comment: click the `switch to copy and paste view` and paste in that error in the updated error. should likely list then where it crashed.

Comment: Remove Comma ',' just before model in the `BlogPostSerializer`

Comment: You are right, MaNKuR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MaNKuR pointed out in a comment to the question, you have an additional comma in your serializer definition at the end of `Meta.fields`:

```
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields=(
            'author',
            'blog_title',
            'blog_description',
        ),
```

Because of this, `Meta.fields` is now a "tuple of tuple of strings" instead of just a "tuple of strings".

When iterating over `fields`, instead of the expected three string elements

```
1. 'author'
2. 'blog_title'
3. 'blog_description'
```

you get only one element that is not a string

```
1. ('author', 'blog_title', 'blog_description')
```

Hence, the internal code of the Serializer complains that it did not get a string like it is supposed to get.